# Why I got different training results from using keras and tf.keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I was using TensorFlow 1.13 and Keras for my research projects. Nowadays, due to some future warnings, I installed TensorFlow 2.0 and tried to use it.

Instead of using Keras as I did before, I used tf.keras and built the same RNN model. i.e.

from keras.layers import Dense (I used before)

v.s.

from tf.keras.layers import Dense (I tried now)

All other codes are the same. However, I get some worse results for using import from tf.keras.layers one. And I am pretty sure it's not a coincidence, I tried cross-validation and run the models many times.

Does anyone have some ideas about why it happens? Are there any differences from the tf.keras.layers and keras.layers? If so, how can we be careful in case we got some "wrose" results?

Comment: Getting a greater loss value sounds like a coincidence because `tf.keras` and `keras` have the same construction. Even `keras` uses TensorFlow as a backend ( if installed ) or Theano ( which is not the case here ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tf.keras is tensorflow's implementation of the keras api. Ideally, using tf.keras should not provide you worse results. However, there might be a mismatch in the versions of both the keras which may/may not give you different results. You can check the version using tf.keras.version function and see if that is the same version of keras that you had used before.
For more details refer:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/overview